# Python for loop being skipped in program

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to write a python program that sends out questions and checks for answers. It has a while True loop in it which is broken when an answer is received. The file "players.txt" just contains a number which is the amount of players currently available to answer the question. The problem I am having with it is that the for loop in the code here:

```
while True:
    myfile = open("players.txt","r")
    print("File: players.txt OPENED")
    for i in range(int(myfile.read())):
        print("For Loop STARTED")
        ftp.retrbinary("RETR answer"+str(i+1)+".txt",open("answer"+str(i+1)+".txt","wb").write)
        myfile = open("answer"+str(i+1)+".txt")
        print("File: answer"+str(i+1)+".txt OPENED")
        if answer == myfile.read():
            scores[i] = scores[i] + 1
            print("Player",str(i+1),"got the correct answer first.")
            correctanswerfound = True

        print("No answer from player",str(i+1),"yet.")
    if correctanswerfound == True:
        correctanswerfound = False
        break

        print("No answer from player",str(i+1),"yet.")
    if correctanswerfound == True:
        correctanswerfound = False
        break
```

Is being skipped. Does anyone know why it is being skipped and any fixes for it.

Comment: because of break call maybe??

Comment: Could you provide a sample of `players.txt` and a few sets of `answer.txt` as well? Besides that, `answer` in `if answer == myfile.read()` is not defined and `scores` is not defined.

Comment: Have you tried using a print statement to validate your assumption that `int(myfile.read())` is something other than zero?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you have in output :

```
>> File: players.txt OPENED
```

But not :

```
>> For Loop STARTED
```

That means that `range(int(myfile.read()))` is in fact an empty list. If I were you I would check my file and my method for reading it.

Answer (score 0):

The "myfile.read()" is not working because the entire file is read in at this point

Use something like

```
line=1
while(line):
  line = myfile.readline()
  for i in range(int(line)):
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.read` method returns the bytes read in string. So when you try `int(myfile.read())` it will provide an invalid literal for int() with base 10 (which is the string obtained by reading the file using myfile.read() )

Comment: He stated that the file contains just a number. `int()` should work fine on it if so.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Tony Vincent said. The read() returns the text that exists in the file which you cannot cast as an int. Change the int(myfile.read()) to len(myfile.read()) which will return the integer length of the string

Comment: He stated that the file contains just a number. It sounds like he wants that number, in which case `int()` is correct.